# Stream stdout/stderr from Chrome or Mozilla to parent process

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to start a Chrome browser or Mozilla browser from the command line and have the browser load a page. I'd like to be able to collect the stdout/stderr from the browser runtime. Is this possible?

The reason I ask is because I would like to run tests in the browser, and the tests will write to stdout/stderr. This is for automated testing of front-end code.

So it would be something like:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const k = cp.spawn('chrome',['http://localhost:3000/#!/foo']);
k.stdout.pipe(testResultParser());
```

Comment: Browser JavaScript can't do that directly but maybe you can find a way to imitate that by [enabling logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and then throw an error or navigate to non-existent URL or something else that will be printed by the browser.

Comment: OTOH maybe Selenium WebDriver, PhantomJS etc. can help.

Comment: Yeah, I would want TAP output, but I don't think most browser test runners have TAP output options